# Do any frameworks or libraries exist for the creation of ePubs in iOS apps?

Tags: objective-c, ios, epub

I would like to take in various file formats, such as HTML or XML documents, process them, and output an ePub document from within my iOS application.

Are there any libraries or example applications that can create properly formatted ePub documents on iOS?

Answer (score 0):

You can had a look on [sigil](http://code.google.com/p/sigil/) which is on C/C++ language. You can export xcode project
from this source code. You can find a manual on their [source code](http://code.google.com/p/sigil/downloads/detail?name=Sigil-0.7.4-Code.zip&can=2&q=). I am also working on Epub publishing. I did not found any suitable library on objective c that export on epub format. So I am doing it manually. If you want to do it manually, [this doc](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/tutorials/x-epubtut/section3.html) will help you to understand the structure of an Epub file.